# Imgur image processing after uploading an image is slow again

Tags: bug, images, uploader, imgur

Imgur image processing after uploading an image is slow again: it used to be below 1 second for the past few weeks, and now  it is back to over five seconds. Tested on different connections, different computers, and different locations (Paris and California). In rare cases (<10%) the Imgur image processing is below 1 second (seems like the first upload is fast and all the subsequent ones are slow).

Demo by [ak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/538012/ak):

[image]

Comment: No repro. Fast for me. Might be related to location.

Comment: Hmm, Paris should be close enough to me (Israel) so yeah, weird.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard Note that my first upload in Paris was quick. All subsequent uploads were slow.

Comment: True. Now each upload takes 3-5 seconds.

Comment: After waiting for a while (~40 minutes), cycle starts over: first upload was fast, then subsequent uploads are slow. Looks like some rate limit that went too strict, perhaps?

Comment: Yep tried adding some images from paint, it slowed down after the 1st upload  [screen recorded - link](https://imgur.com/a/uT8u1zM)